# Background color of sidenav changes when I add a link

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

When I add a link to my sidenav it changes from the sidenav's background color to the main background color in a box shape around the link.[image]

I would like to get rid of the grey behind the spaces and have the sidenav background color (somewhat black) be used instead.

My HTML file:

```
<body>
  <div class="sidenav">
    <h2>Spaces:</h2>
    {% for space in spaces %}
    
    <a href="/{{space}}">{{space}}</a>

    {% endfor %}
  </div>
</body>
```

My CSS file:

```
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: #24252A;
}
.sidenav{
    height: 100%;
    width: 160px;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: #111;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    padding-top: 20px;
    color: #818181;
}

.sidenav a{
    padding: 6px 8px 6px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 25px;
    color: #818181;
    display: block;
}

.sidenav a:hover{
    color: #f1f1f1;
}
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Remove this: `* {background-color: #24252A;` from the code and you are good to go. And define this color for either `body`(if wanted) and individually on elements or class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
*{
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: #24252A;
 }
```

So, You are using * to put `background-color` and that is a global selector and that's why all element `background-color` are change to `#24252A` except `.sidenav` as that element has different background-color define.

The solution should be remove the `background-color` from the `*` (global selector) and set that to `body`.

Like so:

```css
*{
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
body{
    background-color: #24252A;
}
```

Generally putting a `background-color` to the global selector is a bad practice. Hope that answer the questions.

Answer (score 0):

just remove the background-color form the .sidnav
and add whatever background-color your want on the .sidnav a

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #24252A;
}

.sidenav {
  height: 100%;
  width: 160px;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;


  **background-color: #111; "REMOVE"**


  overflow-x: hidden;
  padding-top: 20px;
  color: #818181;
}

.sidenav a {
  padding: 6px 8px 6px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;


  **ADD A BACKGROUND-COLOR**


  font-size: 25px;
  color: #818181;
  display: block;
}

.sidenav a:hover {
  color: #f1f1f1;
}
```